# What is the best way to find longitude and latitude at the last screen touch of the user?

Tags: android, kotlin, latitude-longitude, arcgis, mapview

I develop an android app with the use of  **ArcGIS map** and what im trying  to do is to get the **lat and long** of the **last screen touch**.
I searched for information in the Esri forum and found a solution that advises to use it:

```
   fun getLocation() {
    var viewPoint= mapView.getCurrentViewpoint(Viewpoint.Type.CENTER_AND_SCALE)
    var scale=viewPoint.targetScale
    //var long=??
    //var lat=??

}
```

but i found only the sacle(zoom in or out) at the last touch of the user **and i want
also the latitude and longtitude of it.**

how do i get them from the viewpoint class or maybe from the mapview class

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewpoint returned by `GetCurrentViewpoint` uses the mapView's SpatialReference (probably EPSG:3857 in your case).

Not sure about kotlin but here is how I converted it using ArcGIS .net SDK:

```
var viewPoint = mapView.GetCurrentViewpoint(ViewpointType.CenterAndScale);
var latlon = (MapPoint)GeometryEngine.Project(viewPoint.TargetGeometry, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
var lat = latlon.Y;
var lon = latlon.X;
```